# Getting the value of a previous excel cell in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, attributeerror

So given a cell I want to know the value in which the cell right before it (same row, previous column) has. 
Here is my code and I thought it was working but...:

```
def excel_test(col_num, sheet_object): 
  for cell in sheet_object.columns[col_number]:
    prev_col = (column_index_from_string(cell.column))
    row = cell.row 
    prev_cell = sheet_object.cell(row, prev_col)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
coordinate = coordinate.upper().replace('$', '')
builtins.AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

I have also tried this:

```
def excel_test(col_num, sheet_object): 
  for cell in sheet_object.columns[col_number]:
    prev_col = (column_index_from_string(cell.column))
    row = cell.row 
    prev_cell = sheet_object.cell(row, get_column_letter(prev_col))
```

Can somebody tell me how i can access that, I've also imported everything there needs to be imported.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  **(1)** Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on how to ask questions that are likely to attract useful answers. **(2)** Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38397448/edit) to include the code that initially assigns the value of `coordinate`, and the code that later uses `coordinate` (so we can see what you're trying to do)?

Comment: I'm trying to analyse the comments and decipher whether they are positive or negative. I am fine with that, it's just i don't know how to grab the value from the previous cell

Comment: My comments are intended to be helpful!  I am asking you to add more code to your question because I personally can't answer it without more context.  On SO, "how do I fix this code?" questions will be answered more effectively than "how do I do this?" questions.

Comment: This code sample is incomplete but the error messages are self-explanatory.

Comment: Isn't the error message self explanatory? Your `coordinate` variable is `int`, while it should be a `str`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `cell.offset()` method.

Comment: This does answer the question. `cell.offset()` is exactly what the user requires: it returns cells based on relative row or column offsets from the current cell.